# Error on adding NuGet package from VS-Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nuget, nuget-package

I added the NuGet Package Manager extension in Visual Studio Code, but whenever I try to add a package, after successfully selecting the package name from the search results and the version number, I get the following error in the notification area:

```
The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined
```

Any idea as to what might happen?

Comment: Did you create a new small test project in another directory to check if it is application related?

Answer (score 4):

Duh, my project simply wasn't open. The message isn't greatly explicit, but it was my mistake!